# JS Code on Form submisison causing issues

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I have a optin page in webflow where traffic comes on through ads
On my thankyou page I have embedded a jotform where I want to pass the UTMs
So for this I need the form to redirect the user to a URL with the UTMs which the codes does properly.
The issue is that the preventdefault function sometimes prevents the form submission. So the user is redirected to the thank you page with the proper UTMs but because there is no form submission it is not triggering the zap.

Is there any work around or error handling or form success validation that I can build in?

Here the code:

```
<script>
const runScript = () => {
    const form = document.getElementById("optinms");
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    const utmParams = [
        "utm_source",
        "utm_medium",
        "utm_campaign",
        "utm_term",
        "utm_content",
    ];

    if (form) {
        utmParams.forEach((param) => {
            if (urlParams.has(param)) {
                let field = form.elements[param];
                if (field) {
                    field.value = urlParams.get(param);
                }
            }
        });

        form.onsubmit = (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();

            let params = Array.from(urlParams)
                .filter(([key]) => utmParams.includes(key))
                .map(([key, value]) => `${key}=${value}`)
                .join("&");

            form.action =
                "https://thankyoupage.com" +
                (params ? "?" + params : "");
            form.submit();
        };
    }
};

if (document.readyState === "loading") {
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", runScript);
} else {
    runScript();
}
</script>
```

I tried to add validity check but then I was not redirected..

```
form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
    if (form.checkValidity()) {
        let params = Array.from(urlParams)
            .filter(([key]) => utmParams.includes(key))
            .map(([key, value]) => `${key}=${value}`)
            .join("&");
```

Comment: "*it is not triggering the zap*" - What does this mean?

Comment: so I set up a zap which is triggered by a default webflow form submission

I could send a webhook post request to zapier but wanted to check if there is any way to do this with the default form action